Python, elif caused problem while else didn't
my code didnt show error but it didnt show what I expected.
It is a code to mark "X" on a 3x3 table. Here is the code
as far as I believe it is ok to just use elif multiple times instead of else
my code didnt show error but it didnt show what I expected. When I changed my code just last elif to else, It worked. Like I changed the corresponding code for input of "B3"

line1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
line2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
line3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [line1, line2, line3]
print("Hiding your treasure! X marks the spot.")
position = input() 


if position[0]=="A":
  if position[1]==1:
    line1[0]="X"
  elif position[1]==2:
    line2[0]="X"
  elif position[1]==3:
    line3[0]="X"

elif position[0]=="B":
  if position[1]==1:
    line1[1]="X"
  elif position[1]==2:
    line2[1]="X"
  else:
    line3[1]="X"

elif position[0]=="C":
  if position[1]==1:
    line1[2]="X"
  elif position[1]==2:
    line2[2]="X"
  elif position[1]==3:
    line3[2]="X"


print(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}")




Avoid using map for variable name as it is reserved in python. Check help(map) for details.

The problem is not the if-statements.
The input is saved as a string.
if postition[1] == 1 therefore compares a string with an integer. Adjust the variables accordingly and it should work.
You can make 'position[1]' an integer:
if int(position[1]) == 1:

or compare 'position[1]' with a string:
if position[1] == "1":


When you use input(), it returns a string.
So when you compare position[1] with an integer, it won’t work as expected. To fix this, you can convert the second character of position to an integer using int(position[1]).
Updated Code
line1 = ["⬜️", "⬜️", "⬜️"]
line2 = ["⬜️", "⬜️", "⬜️"]
line3 = ["⬜️", "⬜️", "⬜️"]
map = [line1, line2, line3]

print("Hiding your treasure! X marks the spot.")
position = input()

if position[0] == "A":
    if int(position[1]) == 1:
        line1[0] = "X"
    elif int(position[1]) == 2:
        line2[0] = "X"
    elif int(position[1]) == 3:
        line3[0] = "X"
elif position[0] == "B":
    if int(position[1]) == 1:
        line1[1] = "X"
    elif int(position[1]) == 2:
        line2[1] = "X"
    else:
        line3[1] = "X"
elif position[0] == "C":
    if int(position[1]) == 1:
        line1[2] = "X"
    elif int(position[1]) == 2:
        line2[2] = "X"
    elif int(position[1]) == 3:
        line3[2] = "X"

print(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}")

I think this will work !

It's because you are trying to check equality between string and integer. It always give False.
Here is the fixed version of your code:
line1 = ["⬜️","️⬜️","️⬜️"]
line2 = ["⬜️","⬜️","️⬜️"]
line3 = ["⬜️️","⬜️️","⬜️️"]
map = [line1, line2, line3]
print("Hiding your treasure! X marks the spot.")
position = input() 

char = position[0]
num = int(position[1])

if char == "A":
  if num == 1: line1[0]="X"
  elif num == 2: line2[0]="X"
  elif num == 3: line3[0]="X"

elif char == "B":
  if num == 1: line1[1]="X"
  elif num == 2: line2[1]="X"
  elif num == 3: line3[1]="X"

elif char == "C":
  if num == 1: line1[2]="X"
  elif num == 2: line2[2]="X"
  elif num == 3: line3[2]="X"


print(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}")

